# Python: Adding objects to a list using Classes

Tags: python, list, class

I am new to Classes and hope someone can help me out. I am writing av program where a user can add cars to an existing list of cars. The code I have so far is below. I am probably doing several mistakes here, but the error message I get now is "NameError: name 'car' is not defined". I think I am using the Car Class / Vehicle Class wrong. Anybody got any ideas how I can get on track with this?

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, Make, Model, Year, Mileage, Price):
        self.Makename = Make
        self.Modelname = Model
        self.Yearr = Year
        self.Mileagenw = Mileage
        self.Pricenw = Price
    def getValus(self):
        return self.Makename + " " + self.Modelname+ " " + self.Yearr+" " + self.Mileagenw+" " + self.Pricenw
    def Display(self):
        print("Invetory Unit: Car \n Make: "+ self.Makename + "\n Model: " + self.Modelname+ "\n Year " + self.Yearr+"\n Miles " + self.Mileagenw+" \n Price :" + self.Pricenw)

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, Make, Model,Year,Mileage,Price,numofdoors):
        Vehicle.__init__(self,Make, Model,Year,Mileage,Price)
        self.numofdoorsnw = numofdoors
    def GetCar(self):
        return self.getValus() + ", " + self.numofdoorsnw
    def Display(self):
        print("Invetory Unit: Car \n Make: "+ self.Makename + "\n Model: " + self.Modelname+ "\n Year " + self.Yearr+"\n Miles " + self.Mileagenw+" \n Price :" + self.Pricenw+" \n Number of doors :" + self.numofdoorsnw)

def main():
    vehicles_list = []
    vehicles_list += [Car("Tesla", "S", "2020", "170000", "33000.0", "4")]
    vehicles_list += [Car("Tesla", "X", "2021", "180000", "23000.0", "4")]
    
    newCar = "Y"
    while newCar == "Y":
        print('Input car data')
        Make = input('Merke: ')
        Model = input('Model: ')
        Year = input('Year: ')
        Milage = input('Milage: ')
        Price = input('Price: ')
        numofdoors = input('Number of Doors: ')
        vehicles_list += [Car(Make, Model, Year, Milage, Price, numofdoors)]
        
        newCar = input('Add another car? (Y/N) ')          
    
    print(car.getValus())
       
main()
```

Comment: You can just use `car = vehicles_list[0]` or `car = vehicles_list[1]` to define it. Currently you have no `car` variable defined in global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, Make, Model, Year, Mileage, Price):
        # are you making names unique here? if so, they are in a different namespace so don't have to be different
        self.Makename = Make
        self.Modelname = Model
        self.Yearr = Year
        self.Mileagenw = Mileage
        self.Pricenw = Price
    def getValus(self):
        return self.Makename + " " + self.Modelname+ " " + self.Yearr+" " + self.Mileagenw+" " + self.Pricenw
    def Display(self):
        print("Invetory Unit: Car \n Make: "+ self.Makename + "\n Model: " + self.Modelname+ "\n Year " + self.Yearr+"\n Miles " + self.Mileagenw+" \n Price :" + self.Pricenw)

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, Make, Model,Year,Mileage,Price,numofdoors):
        Vehicle.__init__(self,Make, Model,Year,Mileage,Price)
        self.numofdoorsnw = numofdoors
    def GetCar(self):
        return self.getValus() + ", " + self.numofdoorsnw
    def Display(self):
        print("Invetory Unit: Car \n Make: "+ self.Makename + "\n Model: " + self.Modelname+ "\n Year " + self.Yearr+"\n Miles " + self.Mileagenw+" \n Price :" + self.Pricenw+" \n Number of doors :" + self.numofdoorsnw)

def main():
    # adding unnamed instances of the class Car to a list. Each Car object is an element of the list
    vehicles_list = []
    vehicles_list += [Car("Tesla", "S", "2020", "170000", "33000.0", "4")]
    vehicles_list += [Car("Tesla", "X", "2021", "180000", "23000.0", "4")]
    
    newCar = "Y"
    while newCar == "Y":
        print('Input car data')
        Make = input('Merke: ')
        Model = input('Model: ')
        Year = input('Year: ')
        Milage = input('Milage: ')
        Price = input('Price: ')
        numofdoors = input('Number of Doors: ')
        vehicles_list += [Car(Make, Model, Year, Milage, Price, numofdoors)]
        
        newCar = input('Add another car? (Y/N) ')          
    
    print(car.getValus()) # car is undefined. print the vehicles_list instead, it contains all Car objects you have made.
       
main()
```

Improved version:

```py
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.price = price

    def getValues(self):
        return self.make + " " + self.model + " " + self.year + " " + self.mileage + " " + self.price

    def Display(self):
        print("Invetory Unit: Car \n Make: " + self.make + "\n Model: " + self.model + "\n Year " + self.year + "\n Miles " + self.mileage + " \n Price :" + self.price)

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, Make, Model,Year,Mileage,Price,num_doors):
        Vehicle.__init__(self,Make, Model,Year,Mileage,Price)
        self.num_doors = num_doors

    def GetCar(self):
        return self.getValues() + ", " + self.num_doors

    def Display(self):
        print("Invetory Unit: Car \n Make: "+ self.make + "\n Model: " + self.model+ "\n Year " + self.year + "\n Miles " + self.mileage +" \n Price :" + self.price + " \n Number of doors :" + self.num_doors)

def main():
    vehicles_list = []
    vehicles_list.append(Car("Tesla", "S", "2020", "170000", "33000.0", "4"))
    vehicles_list.append(Car("Tesla", "X", "2021", "180000", "23000.0", "4"))
    
    newCar = "Y"
    while newCar == "Y":
        print('Input car data')
        Make = input('Make: ')
        Model = input('Model: ')
        Year = input('Year: ')
        Milage = input('Milage: ')
        Price = input('Price: ')
        numofdoors = input('Number of Doors: ')

        vehicles_list.append(Car(Make, Model, Year, Milage, Price, numofdoors))
        
        newCar = input('Add another car? (Y/N) ')          
    
    for car in vehicles_list:
        print(car.GetCar())
       
main()
```

result:

```
Input car data
Make: VW
Model: Golf
Year: 2020
Milage: 10000
Price: 20000
Number of Doors: 5
Add another car? (Y/N) n
Tesla S 2020 170000 33000.0, 4
Tesla X 2021 180000 23000.0, 4
VW Golf 2020 10000 20000, 5
```

---

On the point about class namespaces, there is a great talk from Raymond Hettinger explaining those : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8moWQ1561FY

Comment: Thanks a million - this was exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: If the user where to print all the cars of a specific make (based on user input) - any ideas on how that could be done? The input part I understand, but I don`t know the code on how to print rows containing make name "Tesla" f.ex

Comment: The make of the car is an attribute of a car instance, it can be accessed using `car.make`. So when looping through each of the car instances in the `vehicles_list` you can put a check before printing to say `if car.make == 'tesla': ...`. If you are looking to hold lots of data on cars and filter by their attributes, look into the `pandas` Python library, since it seems natural to store that data in a table.

Answer (score 0):

On `print(car.getValus())`, you want to get values from an object of class `Car` called `car` but you never defined this object. You probably want to modify your `main` in the following way

```
def main():
    vehicles_list = []
    vehicles_list += [Car("Tesla", "S", "2020", "170000", "33000.0", "4")]
    vehicles_list += [Car("Tesla", "X", "2021", "180000", "23000.0", "4")]
    
    newCar = "Y"
    while newCar == "Y":
        print('Input car data')
        Make = input('Merke: ')
        Model = input('Model: ')
        Year = input('Year: ')
        Milage = input('Milage: ')
        Price = input('Price: ')
        numofdoors = input('Number of Doors: ')
        input_car = Car(Make, Model, Year, Milage, Price, numofdoors)
        vehicles_list += [input_car]

        newCar = input('Add another car? (Y/N) ') 
     
    for car in veichles_list:
        print(car.getValus())
```

Comment: Thanks @DaSim! Sorry, I did not write this in my initial question but I would like the program to print all the cars (each car on a new line) after the user types "N". When I try your code it only prints the the last car added, even if I move the print outside of the loops. Anybody know how this can be done?

Comment: Code modified, now it should work

Comment: @Armarillo Did it fix your problem?